# Set Content/Media type - Restlet

Tags: java, content-type, restlet

How do you set the content type in Restlet (version 2.0 for google app engine)?  In this case, I'd like to set the content type to ""text/xml".

I have:

```
public class SubResource  extends ServerResource {

 @Get
 public Representation get(Representation representation){

    setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_OK);
    StringRepresentation sr = new StringRepresentation(getSomeXml());

    return sr;
 }
}
```

I'm unsure even if it is a value that is set in the Representation, or if it is set from the ServerResource class the same way that the return code is.

### ANSWER:

```
    StringRepresentation sr = new StringRepresentation(getSomeXml());
    sr.setMediaType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
```

---

Comment: Version 2.0 for google app engine.  I'll edited the post as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying this from some code I wrote a while ago, not sure if things have changed since:

```
Representation representation = new StringRepresentation(body, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
representation.setCharacterSet(CharacterSet.UTF_8);
return representation;
```

For your needs, there's also [MediaType.TEXT_XML](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/data/MediaType.html#TEXT_XML)

Answer (score 8):

Unless there is something in the GAE style that I don't know about, I don't think it needs to be that complicated. This works for me:

```
 @Get( value = "xml" )
 public String myMethodNameHere(){
    return getSomeXml();
 }
```

Comment: Works and works. Seen similar examples in the Restful documentation.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using annotations you could do

```
@Get("txt")
public Representation get() {

    setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_OK);

    return new StringRepresentation("Hi");
 }
```

See [Get](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/resource/Get.html) and [MetadataService](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/service/MetadataService.html#addCommonExtensions%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

The "aha!" here, is that the function must return a Representation().

Thie will work most of the time, but in certain browsers it will return 404 with content.

```
getResponse().setEntity(rep);
getResponse().getEntity().setModificationDate(date);
getResponse().setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_OK);
```

This will show content AND a 200 status code:

```
getResponse().setEntity(rep);
getResponse().getEntity().setModificationDate(date);
getResponse().setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_OK);
return rep;
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotation didn't work for me. I set the content type explicitly.

```
@Get
public Representation represent() {
    StringRepresentation sr = new StringRepresentation("xml string..");
    sr.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    return sr;
}
```